# "ValueError: cannot evaluate a numeric op with unequal lengths" when finding centroids in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Why does the following fail?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({1:[1,2,3,], 2:[4,5,6]},index=np.linspace(0,1,3))
df.T*df.index


ValueError: cannot evaluate a numeric op with unequal lengths
```

Shouldn't this give me a record where every column element is multiplied by the index of the dataframe?

Oddly, this works SOMETIMES in my code. It seems to depend upon the input DataFrame.

For context, the reason I want to do this is that I have a DataFrame where the index are positions, and the elements are weights. I want to get the centroid for each column using these weights and positions. To do this, I found that the following formula was working (with seemingly reasonable results), but sometimes a DataFrame breaks it resulting in the above error

```
centroids = (df_mat.T*df_mat.index).T.sum()/df_mat.sum()
```

Comment: What version of pandas are you on? Float indexes are only recently supported, but still make me very nervous.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that seemed new. Makes me a little nervous also, but rather convenient here. My version is 0.15.2

Comment: The way you've got the problem written, `df_mat` must have equal columns and an index of equal lengths. Are you certain this is the case? Can you build a example that demonstrates your error?

Comment: I apologize, I made a mistake in my example code. The last line should be df.T*df.index

It seems that df.T*df.index.values does what I want, so it must be something about the difference between the way an Index and an array broadcast.

@PaulH I'm not sure what you mean. How would a dataframe have unequal columns? Do you mean unequal length columns somehow?

Comment: No I mean that to broadcast element-wise operations from a vector to an array, the dimensions must be compatible. I'm asking if you're *certain* that your objects have compatible dimensions.

Comment: I think my original mistake confused things.

I am multiplying the index to the tranpose of the dataframe (as in my example). The index must have the same number columns as the transposed dataframe.  i.e. I am forcing this operation to be compatible. 

 So for the short example I give df.index has shape (3,) and df.T has shape (2,3). I think numpy broadcasting (which I thought should apply here) goes from last dimension to the first. So the 3's should match and the operation should be successful. That's why df.T.values*df.index.values will always work.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer my original question of "why the error occurs", but replacing `df.index` with df.index.values` fixes the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({1:[1,2,3,], 2:[4,5,6]},index=np.linspace(0,1,3))
new_df = df.T*df.index.values
print new_df.T
```

results in the desired:

```
     1    2
0.0  0  0.0
0.5  1  2.5
1.0  3  6.0
```